# Angular installation failed

Tags: angular, npm-install, git-bash

When I try to install Angular using bash terminal ($ npm install -g @angular/cli) I face the following error message. I tried everything but still can't get rid of this error. Please help.

```
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/remove-trailing-separator failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have an active internet connection.
If you have one, maybe there is a problem with the proxy settings of your npm installation.

Try following code to reset the proxy settings:

```
npm config get proxy
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

Comment: npm config get proxy returns "null".. the others returned nothing.. still have issue

Answer (score -1):

This problem is occurred when there is a fluctuation in the internet... So always try to check Internet when this problem occurs.

Comment: But this is my answer not my comment...I share this answer with my prospective because  same problem occures in my installation and answer is "Fluctuation in the internet."

Comment: No other answer for this question beside this,I think !!!........but it is helpful for other